# How can I import a .PST to GMail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail-imap

I desperately need the content of an email that I received at my work account (Exchange) from 2 years back.

I no longer work there, my email account is long deleted, but I have a copy of the .PST file from that time, and I know the password for that .PST file.

Is there anyway I can retrieve the mail?

Comment: That said, if Thunderbird can import PST files, it's also really simple to connect to a Gmail account. Then it's just a question of dragging and dropping messages from one to the other. But this is still a better question for [su].

Answer (score 17):

Install Google Mail Migration for Outlook (GAMMO) from Google (free tool). And just run it. It is pretty straight forward. It will import all mails in your pst into your gmail account.

[Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook®](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/outlookmigration)

Comment: Caveat being supported Outlook versions; a lot of people have Outlook 2013 "Click & Run" and that is not supported.

Comment: Can confirm this works with Gmail and not just G Suite.

Comment: Requires a supported version of Outlook be installed on the pc . Is now called GSMMO Google Workspace Migration for Microsoft® Outlook® 
 https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gsmmo

Answer (score 6):

I once had this problem. To solve it, I followed these steps:

1. Installed Microsoft Outlook on my PC
2. Configure the Google Mail Account (POP/IMAP) - for this, I suggest following the steps posted on Google How To
3. Imported the `.pst` file
4. Drag and Drop

I prefer this solution, because my `.pst` file was too big (~4.6GB) to export to Google and I wanted just an attached file of one single message.

Comment: I have tried this option. It does add all the messages to the locally installed Outlook. It then sent 156 messages to the web-based gmail. But, no more are getting transferred to gmail on the web. It's been a few hours now and still shows 156 messages. Do I just need to wait longer or do I need to do something else to make the sync?

Answer (score -4):

Import it into outlook or find a pst viewer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The question is perfectly clarified and importing the pst into a native application that can correctly parse the data is a fine answer.