# How to import a PST file into Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365, exchange, pst

There are [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/723528/how-can-i-import-a-pst-to-gmail) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/1179354/import-11gb-pst-file-to-gmail-without-outlook) about this and they all rely on [Google Workspace Migration for Microsoft® Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gsmmo#) and [Google Workspace Sync for Microsoft® Outlook®](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gssmo#) to do all the work.

Unfortunately, those tools appear to be abandoned.  The latest version of Outlook they support is 2016. I have Outlook 2022.

So, how can I import my Outlook mail into GMail nowadays with Outlook 2022? To be clear, the mail is in Office 365.

I have tried the following already:

- I setup my gmail account in Outlook and attempted to drag messages manually.  This actually works but the process is so slow that it will take several days if not weeks to complete.
- Gmail itself has an "Import Wizard".  However, it insists that I set my Office 365 email as POP.  This is corporate email and I have no way to make them do it.

Comment: This is a question for your company. The fundamentals of import and export have not changed much since Outlook V2002.  Google is not being helpful so your company will need to help.

Comment: Google’s support for Outlook is “Outlook 2016 or newer” it’s not mutually inclusive to only outlook 2016. Without IMAP what you is impossible

Comment: How many messages do you have, and is any antivirus software installed? We did a few PST-to-IMAP transfers via Outlook 2016 drag and drop (not Gmail but inhouse mail server), and it was mostly slow due to AV scanning each message; after disabling that, it took an hour for ~15k messages.

Comment: @Ramhound For the migration tools that I mentioned, it errors out on startup listing supported versions of Outlook.  2016 is the latest.

Comment: We are talking about a paid Google Workspace (or whatever the paid enterprise version currently called), personal Google accounts, requires Outlook 2016+ and device passwords which require 2FA.  But I know for a fact the requirements is Outlook 2016 and newer despite what the error message says.

Comment: @AngryHacker - The migration tools cannot be used, they are null and void. That might be why you are getting an Outlook 2016 error.   My statement about Outlook 2016 deals with the base requirements for security to use IMAP (poorly) within Outlook 2016+  There are no replacements for those tools they were abanded and any personal google account that had not already been used for more than five years ago cannot even use them today even with outlook 2016.  BLUF: The only way you can use Outlook with your Google Account is the one you have determined is "too slow."

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I gave up and using the slow method.  My email only contains 2 years worth of email and it's taking a long while.  Definitely don't recommend for larger archives.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081) seems relevant and applicable to your version of Outlook

Comment: @Ramhound That's exactly what I did.  That's how I dragged all the messages in.  After churning for a long time, it finally finished yesterday night.

Comment: Luckily, I'm glad this difficult process is finally over!

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can I import my Outlook mail into GMail nowadays with Outlook 2022? To be clear, the mail is in Office 365.

Do you mean that you want to import emails of another account in Outlook 365?

If so, you just need to export the emails in Outlook 365 to a .pst file and import it to Outlook 2022.

For the import and export of mail, please refer to:

[Export or backup email, contacts, and calendar to an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91)

[Import email, contacts, and calendar from an Outlook .pst file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/import-email-contacts-and-calendar-from-an-outlook-pst-file-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: By Outlook 2022 you mean Outlook 2021 and. or the current Office 365 build of Outlook? The author wants to import their email from within their .PST files INTO their Google Mail account through IMAP or the discontinued exchange synchronization that was once supported but is no longer supported or more importantly NOT supported by their version of Outlook.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.